# My Simulink model is printing callbacks to the diagnostic window, how do i print to the command window?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a start function callback in my Simulink model. Right now it prints everything to the diagnostic window. I have tried disp, display and fprintf. Is there a setting somewhere to make the default print to the command window instead?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post your code? Are you talking about the `StartFcn` callback? Which release are you using?

Comment: I added some images of the settings window where I have added the callbacks and where I see the outputs. I am looking to have it write to the Command Window instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks the default behaviour is now to print to the diagnostics window and there's no setting to override this. Your only option is probably to use [`evalin`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html):

```
evalin('base','disp(''hi there'')')
```

You can probably create a [Service Request](http://uk.mathworks.com/support/servicerequests/index.html) asking for this to be a future enhancement. MathWorks will probably want to know the reason for doing this though to justify the development effort and prioritise it against other features.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no change in behavior. I tried using eval and evalin with caller instead of base.

Comment: Sorry, I ran out of ideas. You'd better contact MathWorks.